# Match with multiple conditions in $OR

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB I  have 2 conditions

- First condition:

  ```
  "\"userfullname\":{$regex : \"" + filtertext +  "\", $options: 'i'}";
  ```
- Second condition:

  ```
  "\"email\":{$regex : \"" + filtertext +  "\", $options: 'i'}";
  ```

I need to OR condition on this statement so what I did is:

```
matchquery = matchquery + "\"userfullname\":{$regex : \"" + filtertext +  "\", $options: 'i'}"+["%OR:"]+"\"email\":{$regex : \"" + filtertext +  "\", $options: 'i'}";
```

but of course that did not work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/or/)** operator. You essentially want to create a query which has the form

```
var matchquery = {
    '$or': [
        { 'userfullname': { '$regex': \filtertext\, '$options': 'i' } },
        { 'email': { '$regex': \filtertext\, '$options': 'i' } }
    ]
}
```

---

If `filtertext` is a variable then you can use **[`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** constructor which creates a regular expression object for matching text with a pattern. For example:

```
var filtertext = "foo";
var rgx = new RegExp(filtertext, "i");
var matchquery = {
    "$or": [
        { "userfullname": rgx },
        { "email": rgx }
    ]
};
```

To stringify the query, you could try:

```
var filtertext = "foo";
var rgx = new RegExp(filtertext, "i");
var matchquery = '{ "$or":[{ "userfullname": {"$regex": '+ rgx.toString() +'} },{ "email":{ "$regex": '+ rgx.toString() + '} }] } }';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Or](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/or/) Operator & create it like this :

```
var condition1 = 
"\"userfullname\":{$regex : \"" + filtertext +  "\", $options: 'i'}";

var condition2  = "\"email\":{$regex : \"" + filtertext +  "\", $options: 'i'}";


var matchquery = "{ \"$or\" : [ " + condition1  + "," + condition2  +" ]}"
```

Comment: hi i tried your code but it display following error JSON reader was expecting ':' but found '$or'.

Comment: it should work. is there something else which is getting appended to your match query?